# Is it allowed to incentivize users to leave reviews?

Tags: ios-appstore, app-store-connect

I was playing a game and encountered this:

[image]

Is this allowed by Apple? As soon as you click "Yes" and go to the app store review page, it unlocks all of the colors, whether or not you actually leave a review.

Answer (score 1):

If they can force you to make in-app purchases (and spend real money) in order to unlock content, then why wouldn't they be allowed to force you to write a review in order to unlock content?

Plus, as you said yourself, you don't actually have to write a review for the content to be unlocked. You just have to click "Yes".